# SQL string conversion

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to create a procedure where I can pass some alphanumeric values like this:

> my title is "EARTH" from my teacher's book

I have already achieved this by the front end because the query is passed in the form of a variable.

Using a query pass from the front end

```
declare @String nvarchar(1000) 
EXEC RUN(@String )
```

Trying to achieve this

```
EXEC RUN _1(my title is "EARTH" from my teacher's book)
```

The problem is ( " ) and ( ' )

Is there any method to convert it into string or any tool available ?

Comment: From what environment are you trying to run that statement? SSMS? C#? Other?

Comment: I'm Not really sure that `exec run(@string)` means. I've never encountered `exec run` before and also couldn't find it in documentation. Are you sure you're working with SQL Server? Also, `my title is "EARTH" from my teacher's book` isn't a valid SQL statement, what would you expect the output to be?

Comment: @ZoharPeled You are not getting this. It is just an example like <my title is "EARTH" from my teacher's book> is a string and i want to select or insert, anything through the proc

Comment: You're right, I'm not getting this.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE demoRun
@input nvarchar(100)
as

    SELECT @input

GO

EXEC demoRun 'my title is "EARTH" from my teacher''s book'

GO
```

By way of explanation, double quotes may be left unescaped, because SQL uses single quotes to denote a string.  That leaves only one character that you need to escape, being the single quote in teacher's.  This is most easily achieved by doubling the single quote, as shown.

Answer (score 0):

For `'` you must replace it with `''` and for `"` replace this with `\"`.

```
  EXEC RUN _1("my title is \"EARTH\" from my teacher''s book")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF then escape the double quotes with a backslash

```
EXEC RUN _1("my title is \"EARTH\" from my teacher's book")
```

Comment: You can, but never should as it can other very negative effects.